# knockout viewmodel mapping issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

my viewmodel on C# looks like this -

```
public class Level1Child
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
public class Parent
{
    public string name;
    public List<Level1Child> Level1Children { get; set; }    
}
public class Test
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This is the way i am trying to create viewmodel mapping -

```
$.getJSON('Test/GetData/', null, function (value) {
        data = value;

        function Level1ChildViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        }

        function TestViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;

            self.Parent = function (data) {
                this.name = data.name;
                this.children = ko.observableArray([]);
                if (this.children !== null) {
                    var mappedObjects = $.map(data.Level1Children, function (eachSingleObject) {
                        return new Level1ChildViewModel(eachSingleObject);
                    });
                    self.children(mappedObjects);
                }
            };
        }
        var myvm = new TestViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(myvm);
});
```

And this is how i am trying to create the view -

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <!-- ko foreach: children -->
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

But while execution, i am getting the error - children is undefined.
Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the TestViewModel instance does not contains a children property.
Why ? Because this instance has a method named Parent (that creates the children array) but this method is never called.

I think that you can simplify you as follow :

```
function TestViewModel(data) {
     var self = this;    

     self.name = data.name;
     self.children = ko.observableArray([]);

     var mappedObjects = $.map(data.Level1Children, function (eachSingleObject) {
                 return new Level1ChildViewModel(eachSingleObject);
     });
     self.children(mappedObjects);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. What i intend to do here is print the parent name, then print all the children for that parent. Could you please let me know where should i call     self.Parent(data)  ?